# Is there any way to select all child array with just JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a json as below

```
{
    "Shop": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Item": "Item1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Item": "Item2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Item": "Item3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
        
}
```

I would like to select all `Items` with just JsonPath. I have tried as following combinations but I did not get any values

```
$.[Shop[0], Shop[1], Shop[2]].Items

$.[Shop[0].Items, Shop[1].Items, Shop[2].Items]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which JSONPath implementation and programming language you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are looking for `*` wildcard to [select all elements](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/jsonpath-reference.html) in an array:

```
$.Shop[*].Items
```

Gives me:

> [   [
> {
> "Item": "Item1"
> }   ],   [
> {
> "Item": "Item2"
> }   ],   [
> {
> "Item": "Item3"
> }   ] ]

Comment: Thank you for your support but that gives 3 different arrays. I would like to merge result  in one array. I mean I do not want to run nested for-each in business logic.

Comment: @Kerberos you can simply flatten the result array `[..].flat()`. Deal done.

Comment: OK but I think flat() is not a part of xpath?

Comment: My question about xpath. It is possible or not?

Comment: I don't think so. If you are concerned about optimizations like that you may want to stay away from JSONPath altogether and process the JSON using your general language.

Comment: Comparable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819775/how-to-flatten-a-json-with-nested-lists-by-jayway-jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsonpath-cli](https://www.jsware.io/jsonpath-cli/):

```
$.Shop[*].Items[*]
```

gives

```
[{"Item":"Item1"},{"Item":"Item2"},{"Item":"Item3"}]
```

Alternatively,

```
$.Shop[*].Items.['Item']
```

gives

```
["Item1","Item2","Item3"]
```